# Loading different Linux Distribution each time computer starts automatically?

Tags: grub-legacy

I have two Linux distributions (OpenSuSE, Ubuntu) installed on two different partitions. Each time I start my machine, GRUB loads up, allowing me to select one of the two distributions.

I don't want the GRUB to show up, so I limit timeout to zero in /boot/grub/menu.lst, which will most probably make my machine load OpenSuSE each time I start my PC because it's the first option in the menu.lst.

Is it possible that the second time I restart my PC, Ubuntu gets loaded automatically? The third time I restart again, OpenSuSE may get booted while fourth time I restart, Ubuntu may load up and so on?

In other words, how can I make my machine to boot the next OS in menu.lst, the next time it is restarted?

Comment: Would you mind adding some detail: Are you using Karmic (which uses Grub2)? Also, do you share a /boot partition between both distros? Or does one distro's boot partition link to both distros kernel/initrd, etc?

Comment: It's not weird at all! I used to do this with a dedicated Linux partition that would restore Windows using Partimage. Every other boot would go to Linux for a restore, then an immediate reboot back into Windows. (But I used LiLo then with the -R switch IIRC.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I attained the functionality I was looking for by using the 'savedefault' option of GRUB. I used to set it's value to the other operating system at the end of entry of each OS in menu.lst.

Thanks a lot to everyone who tried to help. :)

Comment: +1 Was about to suggest savedefault, but you beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 11):

Put something in the startup scripts to rewrite `menu.lst`.

So have Ubuntu write a version of `menu.lst` that loads OpenSuSE, and have OpenSuSE write a version that loads Ubuntu.

A relatively safe way to do this would be to have 3 files, `menu.lst`, `menu.lst.ubuntu` and `menu.lst.SuSE` and have the scripts do:

```
cp menu.lst.ubuntu menu.lst
```

on SuSE and:

```
cp menu.lst.SuSE menu.lst
```

on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Lilo can do this.

But you might consider a simple script in each OS that sets the *other* OS as the grub default. For example, the following script would modify a `default 1` setting to `default 0`:

```
echo -e "g/default 1/d\ni\ndefault 0\n.\nw" | ed /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

(ed is much like Vi. Run just the first command to see what it's doing.)

On the other OS, you could run the counterpart:

```
echo -e "g/default 0/d\ni\ndefault 1\n.\nw" | ed /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Comment: Thanks jhs. I think it will work out for me. But i will get to LILO if i fail to achieve the functionality with GRUB.

Answer (score 2):

What is your reason/objective to do this?

Have you considered just running two different **virtual machines**? If VMs can be considered, there are a number of different ways to accomplish this from within the host machine itself, without tampering with the guests.